# Java multi-threading example printing message 100 times on different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

I'm tracing this code and I'm trying to figure out what exactly it's supposed to do. I can't get it running on IntelliJ. The run option is greyed out even though I defined the Project SDK. But I just want to know what the code is supposed to do.

I just read a bit of theory on threads. Is it just supposed to display each message 100 times with a timestamp on different threads? And Runnable 4 is an example of how to do it with a lambda correct?

**Main class**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Example02
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        // create runnables
        PrintMessageRunnable pmRunnable1 = new PrintMessageRunnable("Runnable 1");
        PrintMessageRunnable pmRunnable2 = new PrintMessageRunnable("Runnable 2");
        PrintMessageRunnable pmRunnable3 = new PrintMessageRunnable("Runnable 3");

        // passing a runnable using Lambda notation
        Runnable pmRunnable4 = () -> {
            // this is the code inside the run method
            String message = "Lambda Runnable";
            int REPETITIONS = 100;
            int DELAY = 100;

            try {
                for(int i = 1; i <= REPETITIONS; i++) {
                    Date now = new Date();
                    System.out.println(now + ": " + message + "." + i);
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Runnable version interrupted.");
            }
        };

        // specify how many threads the executor service should manage
        int MAX_THREADS = 2;
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);

        // start running
        pool.execute(pmRunnable1);
        pool.execute(pmRunnable2);
        pool.execute(pmRunnable3);
        pool.execute(pmRunnable4);
    }
}
```

**Print Message Runnable class**

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrintMessageRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private String message;
    private int REPETITIONS = 100;
    private int DELAY = 100;

    public PrintMessageRunnable(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            for(int i = 1; i <= REPETITIONS; i++) {
                Date now = new Date();
                System.out.println(now + ": " + message + "." + i);
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Runnable version interrupted.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have 2 threads which prints your message with a timestamp.
The lambda presentation of runnable is correct too.

But the usage of `java.util.Date` is dangerous, bacause of it isn't threadsafe.
Use `LocalDateTime` in multithread application to avoid errors

Comment: Thank you :) I was just reading about making things threadsafe using locks. Going through examples on that right now.

Comment: A single `Date` instance is never used by more than one thread here. So this is perfectly safe.

Comment: If an object instance is NOT used by more than one thread, no need to think about threadsafe indeed.

Comment: It was only recomendation for author of question